# Why does numpy's vectorize function perform twice on the first element

Tags: numpy

The problem is very simple to understand,But it is confusing,
This is my code in python console:

```
import numpy as np
l=[]
def g(x):
    l.append(x)
    return x
k=np.arange(10)
np.vectorize(g)(k)
>>l
>>[0,0,1,2,..,9,10]
```

Why list l have two zeros

Comment: Take another look at the Notes section of the [vectorize docstring](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize).

Comment: You didn't specify the `otypes`.  `np.vectorize` is not as simple a tool as it first appears.  It's good that you are checking this.  But don't spend too much time trying to understand it.  There are more important things in `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because if you do not specify an `otypes` argument to `vectorize` then numpy does not know the output type. It determines this by first running the function provided to vectorize with the first element. Once it knows the output type from this first call it will then call this function for all elements starting with the first one again.

This is mentioned in the [vectorize docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy-vectorize) and examples on the docs but it's easy to miss.