# Unexplained behaviour from vectorized partial function using `numpy` and `functools`

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, functools

I am trying to vectorize a partial function which takes two arguments, both of them lists, then does something to the pairwise elements from the lists (using `zip`). However, I am finding some unexpected behaviour.

Consider the following code:

```py
import functools
import numpy as np

def f(l1,l2):
    l1 = l1 if isinstance(l1,list) or isinstance(l1,np.ndarray) else [l1]
    l2 = l2 if isinstance(l2,list) or isinstance(l2,np.ndarray) else [l2]
    for e1,e2 in zip(l1,l2):
        print(e1,e2)

f(['a','b'],[1,2])

fp = functools.partial(f,l1=['a','b'])
fp(l2=[1,2])

fv = np.vectorize(fp)
fv(l2=np.array([1,2]))
```

The output from the Jupyter notebook is as follows:

```py
a 1
b 2

a 1
b 2

a 1
a 1
a 2
array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

I have two questions:

- First, the type check at the beginning of `f` is necessary because `np.vectorize` seems to automatically fully flatten any input (I get a `int32 not iterable` exception otherwise). **Is there a way to avoid this?**
- Secondly, when the partial function `fp` is vectorized, clearly the output is not the expected one - I am not sure I understand what NumPy is doing here, including the final empty array output. No matter how much I nest `[1,2]` within a list, tuple or array the output seems to be always the same. **How can I fix my code so that the vectorized function `fv` behave as expected - that is the same as `fp`?**

**Edit**
Another try I have done is:

```py
fpv(l2=[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])])
```

whose output is:

```py
a 1
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
```

Comment: `vectorize` passes scalar values to your function.  It also passes a trial input to determine the return dtype.  Your function does not have a `return` so the result is None` (object dtype).

Comment: @hpaulj that explains the last output line, thank you.

Comment: The whole purpose of `vectorize` is to feed broadcastable arrays to a function that only takes scalar parameters.  It has a clear prrformsnce disclaimer.  There is a `signature` parameter that alters the 'scalar' part, but at some performance cost.  Be careful with letting wishes and 'as expected' have priority over documented behavior.

Comment: `f` *should* just expect iterable arguments, and the caller should be responsible for passing *appropriate* iterables based on what `f` is documented to do.

Answer (score 0):

After the changes to `isinstance` I analyzed further:

```
import functools
import numpy as np

def f(l1,l2):
    print('raw', l1, l2)
    l1 = l1 if isinstance(l1,list) or isinstance(l1,np.ndarray) else [l1]
    l2 = l2 if isinstance(l2,list) or isinstance(l2,np.ndarray) else [l2]
    print('preprocessed', l1, l2)
    print('zipped:')
    for e1,e2 in zip(l1,l2):
        print(e1,e2)

print('\ntwo lists')
f(['a','b'],[1,2])

print('\nl1 supplied through funcools.partial')
fp = functools.partial(f,l1=['a','b'])
fp(l2=[1,2])

print('\nvectorized')
fv = np.vectorize(fp)
fv(l2=np.array([1,2]))
```

Output:

```
two lists
raw ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
preprocessed ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
zipped:
a 1
b 2
```

As expected. Two lists [a, b] and [1, 2] zipped together.

```
l1 supplied through funcools.partial
raw ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
preprocessed ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
zipped:
a 1
b 2
```

Same as above, functools.partial just wraps the function with two args into a function with one arg injected by functools and one exposed. Same input, same output.

```
vectorized
raw ['a', 'b'] 1
preprocessed ['a', 'b'] [1]
zipped:
a 1
raw ['a', 'b'] 1
preprocessed ['a', 'b'] [1]
zipped:
a 1
raw ['a', 'b'] 2
preprocessed ['a', 'b'] [2]
zipped:
a 2
```

This is what I would expect vectorize to do: map the function `fp` over the members of the input `l2`.

So I would expect the underlying function calls to `f()`:

```
f(l1=['a', 'b'], l2=1)
(with expected output from zip(): a 1)
f(l1=['a', 'b'], l2=2)
(with expected output from zip(): a 2)
```

This is almost what we see happen, except the first call is reapeated twice.

Minimal reproduction scenario:

```
import numpy as np

np.vectorize(print)(np.array([1,2,3]))
```

Prints 4 lines: 1, 1, 2, 3.

So the unexpected behaviour is in the ndarray class with `np.vectorize`; it seems to add a header to the array which is processed like an element.

This problem was also addressed in [Why does numpy's vectorize function perform twice on the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869745/why-does-numpys-vectorize-function-perform-twice-on-the-first-element).

Here's the fix:

`np.vectorize(fp, otypes=['str'])(l2=np.array([1, 2, 3]))`

Specifying the otypes will eliminate the extra calculation over the first element in the vector.

Comment: The problem is that `fv` seems to consume only scalars i.e. when I print `l2` right at the beginning, I am always getting a scalar no matter how much I nest the input. Also, I am not sure I follow your point about polymorphism here. I have modified the type check to include a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are trying to compare `partial` and `vectorize`.  They have entirely different purposes.

`partial` just lets us specify one argument ahead of time.  It does nothing specific to `numpy`.

Lets modify the function to display more information about the inputs and the iteration.

```
In [75]: def f(l1,l2):
    ...:     print('inputs ',l1,l2)
    ...:     l1 = l1 if isinstance(l1,list) or isinstance(l1,np.ndarray) else [l1]
    ...:     l2 = l2 if isinstance(l2,list) or isinstance(l2,np.ndarray) else [l2]
    ...:     for i,(e1,e2) in enumerate(zip(l1,l2)):
    ...:         print(i,e1,e2)
    ...:     return i
    ...:
```

And applied to your sample lists:

```
In [76]: f(['a','b'],[1,2])
inputs  ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
0 a 1
1 b 2
Out[76]: 1
```

So it gets 2 list inputs, and iterates on their zipped values.

Putting that in `vectorize`:

```
In [77]: fv1 = np.vectorize(f)

In [78]: fv1(['a','b'],[1,2])
inputs  a 1
0 a 1
inputs  a 1
0 a 1
inputs  b 2
0 b 2
Out[78]: array([0, 0])
```

The inputs are quite different.  Instead of 2 lists, `f` gets called several times, with a pair of scalar values.  The first time with `a 1` is the trial call used to determine the return dtype.  I return a number here, you returned `None`

Due to your `if` lines, the scalars are converted to single element lists, and it dones one iteration.

Just for fun, let's make one input a lists of lists,

```
In [79]: fv1([['a'],['b']],[1,2])
inputs  a 1
0 a 1
inputs  a 1
0 a 1
inputs  a 2
0 a 2
inputs  b 1
0 b 1
inputs  b 2
0 b 2
Out[79]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]])
```

Now `f` gives called five times, the trial plus a (2,2) pair - but all with scalar inputs.

I was going to add an example using the `signature` parameter, but don't rememeber enough of the required syntax.

With `partial` execution is no different than when I provide 2 lists, [76]:

```
In [83]: fp = functools.partial(f,l1=['a','b'])
    ...: fp(l2=[1,2])
inputs  ['a', 'b'] [1, 2]
0 a 1
1 b 2
Out[83]: 1
```

With `vectorize` I could simplify the `f` to expect scalar values, and just display them:

```
In [84]: def f(l1,l2):
    ...:     print('inputs ',l1,l2)
    ...:     return 0
    ...: fv2 = np.vectorize(f)    

In [85]: fv2(['a','b'],[1,2])
inputs  a 1
inputs  a 1
inputs  b 2
Out[85]: array([0, 0])
```

In effect `vectorize` just replaces the itertion that you put in the origial `f`.  And it doesn't do it any faster (well to be picky, `vectorize` code does scale a bit better than a list comprehension for large arrays.  But it is not a true `numpy` 'vectorization'.  Nothing it compiled.